# ActionListener for Combobox works only for first column after declaration

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I want to change my second combobox elements by changing the first one's value, but its doesn't work. ActionListener for Combobox works only for the first column after the declaration. If I run debug and press "Run Into" - it works well.
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class face extends JFrame {

public face() {
    super("Test frame");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //              READ FILE           //
    File f=new File("");
    String tname = f.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"1.txt";
    Scanner in = null;
    int i=0;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new File(tname));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (in.hasNextLine())
    list.add(in.nextLine());
    in.close();
    String[] teacherlist = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    JComboBox tcombo = new JComboBox(teacherlist);
    tcombo.setSelectedIndex(1);

    String item = (String)tcombo.getSelectedItem();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(tcombo);

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            File r = new File("");
            //String item = (String)tcombo.getSelectedItem();
            String sname = r.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"aaaa.txt";
            List<String> slist = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner k;
            k=null;
            try {
                k = new Scanner(new File(sname));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (k.hasNextLine())
            slist.add(k.nextLine());
            k.close();
            String[] subjectlist = slist.toArray(new String[0]);
            JComboBox scombo = new JComboBox(subjectlist);
            scombo.setVisible(true);
            panel.add(scombo);
       }
    };
    tcombo.addActionListener(actionListener);
    panel.add(but);
    label.setVisible(false);
    setContentPane(panel);
    }
public static void main(String[] args) 
{JFrame myWindow = new face();
myWindow.setVisible(true);
myWindow.setSize(500,500);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the problem is with this code:

```
JComboBox scombo = new JComboBox(subjectlist);
//scombo.setVisible(true); // not needed components are visible by default
panel.add(scombo);
```

The default size of the combo box is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Whenever you add components to a visible GUI the basic logic is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

However probably a better solution is to add both combo boxes to the GUI when you create the frame. Then when you select an item in the first combo box you just change the "data" in the second combo box. You do this by invoked the `setModel(...)` method on the second combo box.

Check out [Binding comboboxes in swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982260/binding-comboboxes-in-swing/4982576#4982576) for an example of this approach.