# Synchronized Combo Box Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to create synchronized combo box in Java *Swing*. When I choose one of the provinces, the kabupaten (district) combo box will contain all the districts of the selected province. But there's a problem. The district combo box only selects first entry of province combo box and doesn't change when I select another entry in province combo box. What I need to do in order to get fully synchronized combo box? TIA.

```
public void getProvince() {
    DBConnection dBConnection = new DBConnection();
    dBConnection.connection();
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = dBConnection.con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM provinsi";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String provinceName = rs.getString("nama");
            String provinceId = rs.getString("id");
            provinsiCombo.addItem(provinceId);
        }
        dBConnection.con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gagal Terhubung");
    }
}

public void getKabupaten() {
    DBConnection dBConnection = new DBConnection();
    dBConnection.connection();
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = dBConnection.con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM kabupaten WHERE id_prov = '"
                + provinsiCombo.getSelectedItem()
                + "'";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String kabupaten = rs.getString("nama");
            kabupatenCombo.addItem(kabupaten);
        }
        dBConnection.con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gagal Terhubung");
    }
}
```

Comment: _What I need to do in order to get fully synchronized combo box_ You need to add a [listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) to the [provinces] [combo box](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: And db access should be in a separate thread from updating the combo boxes - they should only be updated on the event thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load values dynamically to district combobox based on the value of provinces combo box, you need to use listeners. Example is mentioned below. Better to move loading values from DB to separate class and used the loaded values in your application.

Updated code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

public class SyncronizedComboboxExample extends JPanel
{
  String[] provinces= {"A","B","C"};
  String[] districtsForA = {"l","m","n"};
  String[] districtsForB = {"x","y","z"};
  String[] districtsForC = {"p","q","r"};

  public SyncronizedComboboxExample() {

    JComboBox provincesComboBox = new JComboBox(provinces);

    final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(districtsForA);
    JComboBox districtsComboBox = new JComboBox(model);

    provincesComboBox.addItemListener(e -> {
      if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        DefaultComboBoxModel comboBoxModel;

          if(provincesComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("A")){
            comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(districtsForA);
            districtsComboBox.setModel(comboBoxModel);
          }
          if(provincesComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("B")){
            comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(districtsForB);
            districtsComboBox.setModel(comboBoxModel);
          }
          if(provincesComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("C")){
            comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(districtsForC);
            districtsComboBox.setModel(comboBoxModel);
          }

      }
    });

    add(provincesComboBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(districtsComboBox, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CustomComboBoxDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new SyncronizedComboboxExample();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
  }

}
```

Comment: I think adding an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) to the `JComboBox` is preferable to `ItemListener` because you're only interested in selections.

Comment: @Abra I have updated code to use setModel method. Why ActionListener is more suitable for this task than ItemListener? Can you pls explain?

Comment: Because method `actionPerformed` will be called once only whenever the `JComboBox` selection changes whereas method `itemStateChanged` will be called twice and the OP is only interested in the newly selected item.

Comment: Like the idea of changing the model of the second combo box when an item is selected. Don't like the idea of using all the statements to reset the model. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982260/binding-comboboxes-in-swing/4982576#4982576 for a solution that uses a Hashmap to access the data, removing the need for all the if statement.s.